# raspberry how send e-mail after the network connection

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a raspberry, and I want to share my linux's network to raspberry.(with only cable)
However, it cannot set static ip.

I figured out a way, that is sending a message containing ip after connected to the network, but I do not know how to do.

Or have other way?

Comment: You should prob. ask this in the Raspberry Pi group.
What have you trying to do?  Set RPi to route IP traffic through your Linux box?  Or do you just want to set a Static address to the RPi? Have you checked avahi? RPi usually comes with that installed. 
There are lots of ways, but you have to remember to explain in such a way that we know what you want to do.
You might want to read http://debian-handbook.info/ about the file /etc/network/interfaces (or run the command man interfaces).

Answer (score -1):

Ok, there are some answers to questions with mostly the same contents.

You can set all your network things in `/etc/network/interfaces` as well using other tools for setting up the net in a more dynamic way through GUI. But that is mostly useful for a moving machine, like a laptop. While servers you would like to have static settings.

So, you need to know your RPi:s address, network mask and gateway (which is another name for router).  It are also good to know the DNS server IP address, which usually is the same as the gateway in small home routers (which usually have the services router/firewall/DHCP-server/NAT for your LAN).

So if your RPi:s IPv4 address is `192.168.47.11` (see to it that it isn't delivered to anyone by your DHCP-server, because they you will have strange errors), your netmask is `255.255.255.0` and the router has IPv4 address `192.168.47.1`, then you can add this into the file `/etc/network/interfaces` in your RPi:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.47.11
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.47.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.47.1 8.8.8.8
    dns-serach foo.example.net
```

The last part will tell your RPi that you are using DNS servers `192.168.47.1` and `8.8.8.8` (use getent hosts 8.8.8.8 to who have that one) and your domain for your machines in your LAN is `foo.example.net`.
To get that to work, you need to install the package `resolvconf` with

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install resolvconf
```

And lastly, on your RPi server, change the IP address `127.0.1.1` in `/etc/hosts` to your real IP address, `192.168.47.11` on your machine.  The previous address, `127.0.1.1` is just for laptops and machines that change networks often. On a server that doesn't, just change to the real and some problems will go away.

Lastly, don't forget the `man` pages.  So try the commands `man man`, `man interfaces` and `man resolvconf`.

Hope it helps, good luck.

And don't forget that Raspian are a Debian version, so use these two links to [a book about administration of Debian](http://debian-handbook.info/) and [a web site with information about administration of Debian](https://www.debian-administration.org/).

Comment: Great. Then it would also be great if you mark my answer as an answer for your problem, and even give it a +1. ;-)